# Editing the og:title in the open graph protocol

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a question about editing meta tags... when we created our app, it was in a private beta, so we titled it "OJO Agent Private Beta". However, we are now out of private beta and would like to change the meta tag accordingly. I understand FB policy regarding changing meta tags  is to prevent developers from deploying a bait and switch, but does anyone know how to get an exception, if at all? We have a live product and it's unfortunate that it keeps showing up in feeds with a "private beta" description - I feel it's hurting our click thru.

**Note that og:title and og:type are only editable initially - after your page receives 50 likes the title becomes fixed, and after your page receives 10,000 likes the type becomes fixed.**
-http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Answer (score 0):

Something from this post [facebook caches og:title?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4700865/facebook-caches-ogtitle) may help, by appending a dummy parameter to your URL (either in testing or after going live) would be a way for you to help facebook with it's caching.

But I would try running the scraper first (on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ under "Editing Meta Tags" you'll find...)

curl http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=**{YOUR_URL}**&format=json

Which should force facebook to recheck your tags.